# Is there a way apply a decorator to a Python method that needs informations about the class?

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator, python-decorators

When you decorate a method, it is not bound yet to the class, and therefor doesn't have the `im_class` attribute yet. I looking for a way to get the information about the class inside the decorator. I tried this:

```
import types

def decorator(method):

    def set_signal(self, name, value):
        print name
        if name == 'im_class':
            print "I got the class"

    method.__setattr__ = types.MethodType(set_signal, method)

    return method


class Test(object):
    @decorator
    def bar(self, foo):
        print foo
```

But it doesn't print anything.

I can imagine doing this:

```
class Test(object):
    @decorator(klass=Test)
    def bar(self, foo):
        print foo
```

But if I can avoid it, it would make my day.

Comment: How about doing something with the inspect module? you can do a decorator that retrieve info with this, anyway what information do yo request?

Comment: Hmmm, why can not you use `type(self)` in the wrapper?

Comment: @defyz: Because I want to have access to the class outside of the method call. The purpose is to register the class to an observer, with the method being the callback.

Comment: @Daniel: inspect doesn't have the information before the method is bound either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__setattr__` is only called on explicit `object.attribute =` assignments; building a class does not use attribute assignment but builds a dictionary (`Test.__dict__`) instead.

To access the class you have a few different options though:

1. Use a class decorator instead; it'll be passed the completed class after building it, you could decorate individual methods on that class by replacing them (decorated) in the class. You could use a combination of a function decorator and a class decorator to mark which methods are to be decorated:

   ```
   def methoddecoratormarker(func):
       func._decorate_me = True
       return func

   def realmethoddecorator(func):
       # do something with func. 
       # Note: it is still an unbound function here, not a method!
       return func

   def classdecorator(klass):
       for name, item in klass.__dict__.iteritems():
           if getattr(item, '_decorate_me', False):
               klass.__dict__[name] = realmethoddecorator(item)
   ```

   You could use a metaclass instead of a class decorator to achieve the same, of course.
2. Cheat, and use [`sys._getframe()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to retrieve the class from the calling frame:

   ```
   import sys

   def methoddecorator(func):
        callingframe = sys._getframe(1)
        classname = callingframe.f_code.co_name
   ```

   Note that all you can retrieve is the *name* of the class; the class itself is still being built at this time. You *can* add items to `callingframe.f_locals` (a mapping) and they'll be made part of the new class object.
3. Access `self` whenever the method is called. `self` is a reference to the instance after all, and `self.__class__` is going to be, at the very least, a sub-class of the original class the function was defined in.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept this one, not for the _getframe but because I will fallback on class decorators.

Comment: @e-satis: Registering the class is, afterall, effectively a class-level operation, so using a class decorator makes sense just like a metaclass would.

Comment: @e-satis: You could go one level of ugliness (creativeness) further, and stick a `__metaclass__` in the `callingframe.f_locals` dictionary, to assign a metaclass to the class..

Comment: I got a problem with metaclasses: I'm aiming django models, and they are already implemented using a metaclass. So I can't override it. It's funny, considering my answers on metaclass if probably the most popular Python answer ever (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

My strict answer would be: It's not possible, because the class does not yet exist when the decorator is executed.

The longer answer would depend on your very exact requirements. As I wrote, you cannot access the class if it does not yet exists. One solution would be, to mark the decorated method to be "transformed" later. Then use a metaclass or class decorator to apply your modifications after the class has been created.

Another option involves some magic. Look for the implementation of the `implements` method in `zope.interfaces`. It has some access to the information about the class which is just been parsed. Don't know if it will be enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html). They let you implement a `__get__` that is used when an attribute is accessed, and can return different things depending on the object and its type.

Comment: Yes, just like setattribute does, but in that particular case, it doesn't work. i'm gessing these attributes are set at the C implementation level, and don't trigger the descriptors.

Comment: @e-satis: `__get__` works fine *when the method is retrieved via attribute access. Which is never, at class building time.

Answer (score 0):

Use method decorators to add some marker attributes to the interesting methods, and use a metaclass which iterates over the methods, finds the marker attributes, and does the logic. The metaclass code is run when the class is created, so it has a reference to the newly created class.

```
class MyMeta(object):
  def __new__(...):
    ...
    cls = ...
    ... iterate over dir(cls), find methods having .is_decorated, act on them
    return cls
def decorator(f):
  f.is_decorated = True
  return f
class MyBase(object):
  __metaclass__ = MyMeta
class MyClass(MyBase):
  @decorator
  def bar(self, foo):
    print foo
```

If you worry about that the programmer of `MyClass` forgets to use `MyBase`, you can forcibly set the metaclass in `decorator`, by exampining the globals dicitionary of the caller stack frame (`sys._getframe()`).

Comment: this will work, but implies using a metaclass. The whole purpose of the exercice being making the observer registration easier, adding a meta class will not help. I already can register the class, I just want to make it more pleasant.

Comment: Installing a metaclass automatically (by the decorator) is very easy to use, but complicated to implement. Other solutions are cumbersome to use, but easy to implement. You didn't mention which kind of easiness you are interested in, so I fail to see why my answer didn't answer your question.

Comment: There is no way to add the metaclass to the class from the method decorator since you don't have access to the class. And if you use a class decorator, then you don't have a problem.

Comment: ``There is no way to add the metaclass to the class from the method decorator'' -- this is false. Something like `sys._getframe().f_back.f_locals['__metaclass__'] = MyMeta` worked for me last time I needed that.

Comment: Yeah but in that case we are back to Martijn Pieters's play ground :-)

Comment: From your question it's not obvious if you need a reference to the class or the class name is enough. If you need a reference, then my answer solves your problem (and it is very easy to use, but ugly to implement), while Martijn Pieter's answers don't. This is the exact reason why I wrote my answer: it solves the problem if the requirements are refined in a very specific way.

Comment: As I said in other comment, using a metaclass is out of the question as I'm aiming Django classes which already implement metaclasses.